# Dataset runtime creation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm optimizing my system and I'm trying to do a more dynamic form of dataset creation to do inserts, updates, delete, and even searches. I was able to get here trying to make an insert, but a DatasetProvider error occurs even though I have already directed it to the ClientDataset, and the error occurs when opening the TClientDataSet:

```
procedure TF_Teste.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR
  sdsTemp : TSQLDataSet;
  dspTemp : TDataSetProvider;
  cdsTemp : TClientDataSet;
  dsTemp : TDataSource;
begin
  try
    //Cria o TSQLDataSet
    sdsTemp := TSQLDataSet.Create(nil);
    sdsTemp.SQLConnection := DMPrin.HYPERBD;
    sdsTemp.Close;
    sdsTemp.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM CLIENTE';

    //Cria o TDataSetProvider
    dspTemp := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
    dspTemp.Name := 'dspProvider';
    dspTemp.DataSet := sdsTemp;
    dspTemp.Options := dspTemp.Options + [poAllowCommandText];
    dspTemp.Options := dspTemp.Options + [poUseQuoteChar];

    //Cria o TClientDataSet
    cdsTemp := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
    cdsTemp.ProviderName := dspTemp.Name;

    cdsTemp.Open; //Nesse momento ocorre o erro de "Missing dataset provider ou data packet"
    cdsTemp.Append;
    cdsTemp.FieldByName('NOME').AsString := 'Teste dataset';
    cdsTemp.ApplyUpdates(0);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(sdsTemp);
    FreeAndNil(dspTemp);
    FreeAndNil(cdsTemp);
  end;
end;
```

I'm still going to optimize the code further by putting it into a function, but now I'm just trying to make it work.
Could you help me with this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although not relevant to your Q, this is still a rather important remark. You MUST create an object BEFORE you enter its `try..finally` block. In this case, if for instance `TSQLDataSet.Create(nil);` raises an exception, you will do `sdsTemp.Free` on a random pointer `sdsTemp`, which is very bad. (Local vars of unmanaged types are not initialized.) Similarly for the three other objects. Always use the idiom `X := TX.Create; try {use X} finally X.Free; end`. In this case, I'd thus recommend three levels of `try.finally`, one for each resource. (Otherwise, at least init your pointers b4 `try`.)

Comment: Use `sdsTemp.SetProvider(dspTemp)`

Comment: Setting the cds's ProviderName to link it to the DSP will only work if they have the same non-Nil Owner, and yours do not.  So use @nolaspeaker's suggestion instead.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you for this information. Glad to know.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand. Very nice explanation. I have certainly learned quite a few things today.

Comment: @nolaspeaker. You solved my problem. Many thanks!